# Backlight Keyboard Not working

Tags: backlight

I have a backlight Keyboard Banda k77.
Recently I switched from Windows to Ubuntu 22 LTS version.

In windows, when I press scroll lock button. The backlight would turn on and off.

But after switching to Ubuntu, I realized that it's not working.
I researched and tried so many methods.

Ex.

```
xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Scroll_Lock"
```

It didn't work,

Then I tried this code

```
Xset led 3
```

But I failed again and again.
I tried so many other methods.